# Prestashop - fields_value added only single char

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

I have problem with prestashop and form helper. I have form with two input text, i could add default value with fields_value. Unfortunately it doesn't work. My form:

```
public function displayForm()
{
    $default_lang = (int)Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
    $fields_form = array();
    $fields_form[0]['form'] = array(
        'legend' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('My module settings')
        ),
        'input' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => $this->l('Box Description: '),
                'name' => 'description',
                'lang' => true,
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => $this->l('Box Description: '),
                'name' => 'test_name',
                'lang' => true,
            )
        ),
        'submit' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            'class' => 'btn btn-default pull-right'
        )
    );
    $languages = Language::getLanguages();
    $helper = new HelperForm();
    $helper->module = $this;
    $helper->name_controller = $this->name;
    $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;
    $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');

    $helper->default_form_language = $default_lang;
    $helper->allow_employee_form_lang = $default_lang;
    $helper->languages = $this->context->controller->getLanguages();

    $helper->title = $this->l('tester2');
    $helper->show_toolbar = true;        // false -> remove toolbar
    $helper->toolbar_scroll = true;      // yes - > Toolbar is always visible on the top of the screen.
    $helper->submit_action = 'homepage_settings';
    $helper->tpl_vars = array(
        'fields_value' => array('description' => $this->l('hello'), 'test_name' => 'tester2'),
        'languages' => $this->context->controller->getLanguages(),
        'id_language' => $this->context->language->id
    );
    return $helper->generateForm($fields_form);
}
```

When i install module, and go to module configuration then i see 2 form input text with single char instead my text[image]

What am I doing wrong? Next question is what i can do, to my module to make my module work in multi store mode? In the final version, the data in the form will be supplemented from the database, but I want to find out why it does not complete the fields with the whole text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fields are multi languages.

try this:

```
'fields_value' => array(
    'description' => array(1 => $this->l('hello')), 'test_name' => array(1 => 'tester2')),
```

Comment: Works fine :) but how can I add support for multilingual fields? I am looking for a solution day 2 and I can't manage :( I would like to make these fields multilanguage and save them to the database in this form.